# ssh into fedora inside virtual box over internet

Tags: linux, ssh, network-interface

I am running fedora server in a virtual box inside a windows 7 host.
I can ssh into fedora from this windows 7 host.

How ever, I stay out of my place most of the times with a laptop at my disposal, but its config doesn't allow me to run vms on it.

What I am looking for is ssh-ing into my VM from my laptop over internet.

Is this possible ? if yes, how do I have to configure it ?

My virtual box is set up with 2 adapters i) NAT with port forwarding and ii) Host Only Adapter.

I am very new to linux and I need some help.

Comment: We need more information on the networking setup - are you bridging the VM into the same network or do you have some form of NAT?

Comment: I've two adapters in the VBox. One is NAT and the other is Host-Only adapter set to a static ip.

Comment: The question is whether the guest is directly visible from the outside. If not, you'll need to set up some sort of traffic forwarding on the host.

Comment: I forgot to mention, there is port-forwarding enabled in the NAT. how to set up the traffic forwarding on the host ?

Comment: there is an option called 'network bridge' in your virtual box settings. just click on it and select the interface you want to use.

Comment: Do I put it in adapter 3 i.e keep the NAT and the Host Only adapter intact ?